# "X is brave. Y also is brave (bla-bla)", or "Y is also brave (bla-bla)", or "Y is brave also (bla-bla)"?

Tags: word-order

Which of these variants is clear and *unambiguous*?
(bla-bla) is some very long phrase like "as everybody knows".

Comment: I would go with "is also brave" most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three work, although [this page](http://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/also.html) suggests that "also" should come *after* the "to be" verb.  So:

> [Y] is also brave.

However, this feels to me like one of grammar rules that is "more honored in the breach than in the observance", meaning that it's frequently broken.  I don't think it matters much, but you should be consistent in your own writing.

In addition, [the placement of "also" can change the nuance of the sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16338/how-do-i-use-also-in-a-sentence).